# squash commits after rebasing

Tags: git, rebase, squash

I've worked on my branch and made 20 commits. Then I rebased against master. Now my branch has the latest commits from master, which go up to today, then the 20 commits of my own. The git log shows my 20 commits together, however the time of commits shows my commits mixed in with other commits made to master (e.g. my-commit#1; coworker-commit; my-commit#2; my-commit#3; coworker-commit#4). When I try to rebase and squash just my 20 commits to one, it appears the commits made by my coworkers are interfering. The simple solution would have been to squash before rebasing, but it's too late for that. Is this really a problem or am I misunderstanding?

I rebase with:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~20
```

then change 'pick' to 's' for all 20 of the latest commits listed. The commit before mine remains as is. As soon as I save from here I get the error in my terminal:

```
error: could not apply 1234abc...21st commit message foobar
```

Comment: Something weird here.  When you rebased against master, all of the new commits from master should have gone in underneath yours.  Because that's what a rebase is: rewinds your 20 commits, applies new commits from master, then creates new commits from your old ones on top...

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "When I try to rebase and squash just my 20 commits to one, it appears the commits made by my coworkers are interfering." by giving the command(s) you issue and the actual result.

Comment: @wim but only the commit times are the time you rebase. The author times are not changed.

Comment: @wim - so they do 'go underneath' and a 'git log' shows all 20 of my commits together. However the 21st commit is thrown in the error, which is: error: could not apply 12345abc4...21st commit message foo

Comment: @Vampire - updated with some more pertinent info, thanks